# AWK replace null column with the previous row column value

Tags: awk

I have a series of field-delimited files (symbol | ) with varying column widths:

**File 1**:

```
2p              | 2P*    |  1/2 |    2 |                 10.19880615024                       |
2s              | 2S     |  1/2 |    2 |                 10.19881052514816                    |
2               |        |      |    8 |                 10.1988358                           |
2p              | 2P*    |  3/2 |    4 |                 10.19885151459                       |
3p              | 2P*    |  1/2 |    2 |                 12.0874936591                        |
3s              | 2S     |  1/2 |    2 |                 12.0874949611                        |
3               |        |      |   18 |                 12.0875052                           |
3d              | 2D     |  3/2 |    4 |                 12.0875070783                        |
```

**File 2:**

```
2s2.2p3            | 4S*    |  3/2 |    4 |             0.0000000               |
2s2.2p3            | 2D*    |  5/2 |    6 |             2.3835298               |
2s2.2p3            |        |  3/2 |    4 |             2.3846100               |
2s2.2p3            | 2P*    |  1/2 |    2 |             3.5755704               |
2s2.2p3            |        |  3/2 |    4 |             3.5756182               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  1/2 |    2 |            10.3259087               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    |        |  3/2 |    4 |            10.3300944               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    |        |  5/2 |    6 |            10.3358956               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 2P     |  1/2 |    2 |            10.6796703               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    |        |  3/2 |    4 |            10.6899808               |
```

and I would like to fill the blanks in the second column with the corresponding values in the last non-NULL column above:
Example for **file 2**:

```
2s2.2p3            | 4S*    |  3/2 |    4 |             0.0000000               |
2s2.2p3            | 2D*    |  5/2 |    6 |             2.3835298               |
2s2.2p3            | 2D*    |  3/2 |    4 |             2.3846100               |
2s2.2p3            | 2P*    |  1/2 |    2 |             3.5755704               |
2s2.2p3            | 2P*    |  3/2 |    4 |             3.5756182               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  1/2 |    2 |            10.3259087               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  3/2 |    4 |            10.3300944               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  5/2 |    6 |            10.3358956               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 2P     |  1/2 |    2 |            10.6796703               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 2P     |  3/2 |    4 |            10.6899808               |
```

This question is similar to the one in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182580/awk-to-fill-empty-column-value-with-previous-non-empty-column-value) where I can do this in the first column using awk through the command:

`awk -F"|" '/^ /{$0=(x)substr($0,length(x)+1)}{x=$1}1' "$file"`

however I am not knowleadgeable enough to make it work in the second column (or any arbitrary colum for that matter).

Can someone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your `file2` as an example, you may use this `awk` command:

```sh
awk -v c=2 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"} $c ~ /^[ \t]*$/ {$c = p} {p = $c} 1' file

2s2.2p3            | 4S*    |  3/2 |    4 |             0.0000000               |
2s2.2p3            | 2D*    |  5/2 |    6 |             2.3835298               |
2s2.2p3            | 2D*    |  3/2 |    4 |             2.3846100               |
2s2.2p3            | 2P*    |  1/2 |    2 |             3.5755704               |
2s2.2p3            | 2P*    |  3/2 |    4 |             3.5756182               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  1/2 |    2 |            10.3259087               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  3/2 |    4 |            10.3300944               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 4P     |  5/2 |    6 |            10.3358956               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 2P     |  1/2 |    2 |            10.6796703               |
2s2.2p2.(3P).3s    | 2P     |  3/2 |    4 |            10.6899808               |
```

To populate 3rd column just pass `c=3` in place of `c=2`.

Comment: Thanks that worked for column 2, I'm testing with column 3 to check how I can generalize your solution

Comment: Check my more generic solution now. You can pass `c=3` to populate 3rd column instead of 2nd.

Comment: That works too, simple and elegant, thanks

Comment: ^1 That'll behave the same in any awk, there's nothing gawk-specific in it.

Comment: Oh yes you are right, three is nothing specific to gnu aqk

Comment: Thats a wonderful solution.. Is there a way I can apply this logic to multiple columns ? Like say for example columns 1 till 5 ?

Comment: @ChetanSP: You will need to run a loop from 1 to 5 and store each value in an array indexed by column number.

Comment: @anubhava Thank you for the idea. Out of the total 18 columns in my file, the below snippet replicates data for the first 5 only.

awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"}
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF-13; i++)
            if ($i ~ /[^[:blank:]]/) f[i]=$i
            else $i = f[i]
        print
    }
' ' sourceFile.csv >> ProcessedFile.csv

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to a previous version saying the file was tab separated...*

If that column doesn't have values like `0P` or `0D*`, this might be helpful for you:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}!$3{$3=e}{print;e=$3}' file
```

Explanation:

- Set field separators to tab only
- If `$3` is empty, set `$3` to variable `e`
- print line
- set variable `e` to `$3` for next record

Comment: this runs, however it doesn't seem to be changing anything

Comment: @doktorcaligari Are you sure your input file is *tab* separated as you wrote in your question? I get the exact output you wrote. I had to convert your source file however, because you posted spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, you're right, I said tab delimited, that was a typo I meant "field delimited" (with |), my bad I will correct the question for future reference

Comment: That would fail if $3 evaluated numerically to 0

Answer (score 0):

This will take care of all fields iin the file

```sh
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = "|"}
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
            if ($i ~ /[^[:blank:]]/) f[i]=$i   # remember the value of this field
            else $i = f[i]                     # use the previous field value
        print
    }
' file ...
```

This of course can't do anything about empty fields in the first line of the file.

If you use GNU awk, you can write the results back to the file:

```sh
gawk -i inplace '...' file ...
```